# Array does not store values c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this code:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <bits/stl_algo.h>
#include <valarray>
#include "A.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
char t[5];

//cout << argc;
if(argc > 2){
    int num_ = argc - 2;
    A arr[num_];
    //cout << num_rotors;
    for(int i = 0; i < num_; i++){
        arr[i].generateArray(argv[1 + i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
        cout << arr[0].array[i] << " ";
    }
}

return 0;
}


//A.cpp
#include <iosfwd>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class A : {

public:
    A();

    int array[26] = {0};

    void generateArray(char *filename);

    void printarr(void);
};

void A::generateArray(char *filename) {
    ifstream file(filename);
    if (file.is_open()) {
        string in;
        int ind = 0;
        while (file >> in >> ws) {
            this->array[ind] = atoi(in.c_str());
            cout << this->array[ind] << " ";
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error opening file " << filename << '\n';
    }
}

void A::printarr(void) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << '\n';
}

A::A() { }
```

And i get one line of sensible output from inside method and another one of zeroes. So clearly the values are either not stored in an array during 'generateArray' or array gets cleared out after that. Can anyone point me in a direction of an error?

Or does that array get destroyed and I should simply allocate it on stack??

That produces:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

for me. First line is an actual input and is being printed from generateArray method

Comment: Can't reproduce. I get `0 1 2 3 4` printed out three times.

Comment: You do not need the void in `void A::generateArray(void){` i.e `void A::generateArray(){` will suffice

Comment: Result is here: `0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4`, no problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
A arr[num_];
```

is illegal in C++. If it seems to compile for you, you may be using a compiler extension whose behaviour is hard to predict.  To do this in a standard fashion, write:

```
std::vector<A> arr(num_);
```

Secondly, in this piece of code:

```
int ind = 0;
while (file >> in >> ws) {
    this->array[ind] = atoi(in.c_str());
    cout << this->array[ind] << " ";
}
```

You store all of the values in `array[0]`, with the last stored value being `0` which would explain why you get zeroes in your output. You probably meant to have `ind++` in there somewhere; but you also should check that `ind` does not reach `26`.

Comment: well this is such a nasty error. Thank you! Didn't even expect a mistake there, so wasn't even paying attention to that. That's exactly what it is, as the last number in input is 0. ghrrr

Comment: @user2407413 consider using `std::vector` instead of `array`, and using the `push_back` function to insert into the array. Then you avoid all this sorts of error and buffer overflows.